# Heroku says : Cannot find module 'socket.io'

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

I'm deploying an node.js app with deps/modules like : stylus, express, socket.io on heroku.

The beginning of the server.js

```
/**
 * Bootstrap app.
 */

// I've tried with and without that line... not sure what it does
require.paths.unshift(__dirname + '/../../lib/');



/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

// I've tried with "socket.io", "./socket.io" and "Socket.IO"
var express = require('express')
  , stylus = require('stylus')
  , nib = require('nib')
  , sio = require('socket.io');
```

The file package.json

> {
>       "name": "test.io"   , "description": "blabla"   , "version": "0.0.1"   , "dependencies": {
>           "express": "2.3.11"
>         , "jade": "0.12.1"
>         , "stylus": "0.13.3"
>         , "nib": "0.0.8"
>       } }

So the one and only heroku web worker crash. Here's the log :

```
2011-10-24T09:15:27+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2011-10-24T09:15:35+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2011-10-24T09:15:35+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to created
2011-10-24T09:15:35+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-10-24T09:15:39+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-10-24T09:15:39+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-10-24T09:15:39+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-10-24T09:15:41+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2011-10-24T09:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-10-24T09:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]: node.js:134
2011-10-24T09:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]:         throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
2011-10-24T09:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]:         ^
2011-10-24T09:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io'
2011-10-24T09:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:320:11)
2011-10-24T09:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function._load (module.js:266:25)
2011-10-24T09:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:348:19)
2011-10-24T09:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:18:11)
2011-10-24T09:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:404:26)
2011-10-24T09:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object..js (module.js:410:10)
2011-10-24T09:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:336:31)
2011-10-24T09:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function._load (module.js:297:12)
2011-10-24T09:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:423:10)
2011-10-24T09:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)
2011-10-24T09:15:41+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-10-24T09:15:44+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

So, any ideas ? Ever happened to anyone ?

Answer (score 8):

I believe you should add socket.io in dependencies in package.json.

```
{ "name": "test.io" , "description": "blabla" , "version": "0.0.1" , "dependencies": { "express": "2.3.11" , "jade": "0.12.1" , "stylus": "0.13.3" , "nib": "0.0.8" , "socket.io" : "0.8.5" } }
```

Or just do this:

`npm install socket.io --save`

Which will install the latest version of socket.io and add it to the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

```
npm install socket.io
```

did the trick for me. If you are under windows make sure you are running it as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

> These are solutions to socket.io related problems

> I hope i will work

1. Ports in your (index.js or server.js) & (index.html and your client.js) port must be different. (refer below code)

> =============your index.js file ======================

> (port here is 8000)

```
const express = require("express")
var app = express();
const http = require('http')
var server = http.createServer(app);
  
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000
server.listen(port,()=>
{
    console.log("Listening at port => "+port)
});
var io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: '*',
    }
});

const cors = require("cors")
app.use(cors())
```

> =============your client.js file ======================

> port here is 8080

```
const socket = io.connect('https://localhost:8080/')
```

> =============your index.html file ======================

> port here is 8080

```
 <script defer src="https://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"> 
 </script>
```

> Remember your "server.js or index.js" port should be different from "client.js" port (Rememeber this is important)

> (index.html and your client.js) port must be same

2. You should always use 'http' while working with socket.io (refer above code)
3. U may not included cors as it allows u to have more resourses , without cors heroku prevent some dependencies to not install in heroku (refer above code)
4. Try replacing "io" to "io.connect"

   const socket = io.connect('https://localhost:8080/')
5. Must write  tag at the end in the HTML
6. U may forget to add this code which is must in "socket.io"

It is required in your html file

7. delete "node_modules" and "package-lock.json"
   and write "npm i" in cmd
8. This should be in package.json 's scripts

   "start":"node index.js",

I am not talking about nodemon , use simple node over here

9. May be version is creating a problem , u can avoid it by copying all "devDependencies" to "dependencies" in "package.json" and put "*" in version like this

   "dependencies": {

   "cors": "*",

   "express": "*",

   "nodemon": "*",

   "socket.io": "*"

   },

   "devDependencies": {}

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you have socket io installed? Try running:

```
npm install socket.io
```

This will install the latest socket.io available in nodes packet repository.